# Trying to access e-learning but getting error saying "Error initilializing communications with LMS"

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, java, internet-explorer, java-applet

Does anyone know how to solve this problem when accessing e-learning?

[image: E-learning error here]

I'm not sure if this is a Java related error. I've followed whatever the e-learning's instruction about this and I have searched for it on google but I only found nothing (still unsolved according to my search). I've tried in Windows 10 but no luck and tried in a virtual machine still no luck. Adding exceptions to Java security is also useless. Upgrading JRE is also useless. The instruction should be done in Internet Explorer. For full details:

- Operating system: Windows 7 Professional 32-bit
- Browser: Internet Explorer 8
- Java version: Java Runtime Environment 8

I've tried everything I can do so if anyone knows how to fix it I would highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Here's the debug information after pressing OK:

```
0:Tue Jun 14 02:16:26 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - Trying to create MSXML2.XMLHTTP in VBScript
1:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - intReCheckLoadedInterval=250
2:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - intReCheckAttemptsBeforeTimeout=240
3:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - IFrameLoaded 
4:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - In GetAICCURL
5:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - GetQueryStringValue Element 'AICC_URL' Not Found, Returning: empty string
6:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - Querystring value = 
7:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - GetAICCURL returning: 
8:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - In DetectPreferredCommMethod, checking XMLHTTP
9:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - Checking IFrame
10:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - blnCanUseXMLHTTP=true
11:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - AICCComm - blnCanUseIFrame=true
12:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - ----------------------------------------
13:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - ----------------------------------------
14:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In Start - Version: 3.8.2 Last Modified=04/10/2014 16:29:51
15:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Browser Info (Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E))
16:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - URL: https://ukpeoplestuff.com:8888/contentstorage/PeopleStuff_CrewTrainer/index_lms.html
17:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - ----------------------------------------
18:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - ----------------------------------------
19:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In ClearErrorInfo
20:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - GetQueryStringValue Element 'StandAlone' Not Found, Returning: empty string
21:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - GetQueryStringValue Element 'ShowDebug' Not Found, Returning: empty string
22:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - strStandAlone= strShowInteractiveDebug=
23:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Standard From Configuration File - SCORM
24:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Using Standard From Configuration File - SCORM
25:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In LMSStandardAPI strStandard=SCORM
26:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Calling Standard Initialize
27:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_Initialize
28:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_ClearErrorInfo
29:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Grabbing API
30:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_GrabAPI
31:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Searching with improved ADL algorithm
32:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_GetAPI
33:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - SCORM_GetAPI, searching parent
34:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_ScanParentsForApi, win=https://ukpeoplestuff.com:8888/contentstorage/Oracle_SCORM_Adapter/Oracle_SCORM_Adapter.html?LMS_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fukpeoplestuff.com%3A443%2FOA_HTML%2FOA.jsp%3Fpage%3D%2Foracle%2Fapps%2Fota%2Fplayer%2Fwebui%2FPlayerLmsApiRN%26addBreadCrumb%3DS%26OALAF%3DoaText%26transactionid%3D1866399081%26oapc%3D14%26oas%3DsCOuz_BVMP5p5Wh1n9_CBQ..&starting_url=https%u003a//ukpeoplestuff.com%u003a8888/contentstorage/PeopleStuff_CrewTrainer/index_lms.html&lms_log_debug=on&lms_signed=on&lms_debug=on
35:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - SCORM_GrabAPI, returning
36:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Calling LMSInit
37:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_CallLMSInitialize
38:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_GrabAPI
39:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - SCORM_GrabAPI, returning
40:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Calling LMSInitialize
41:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - strResult=false
42:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Detected failed call to initialize
43:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In SCORM_SetErrorInfo
44:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - intSCORMError=101
45:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - strSCORMErrorString=General exception
46:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - strSCORMErrorDiagnostic=java.lang.ClassFormatError: oracle/apps/ota/lms/LMSJava2Helper$1 at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSJava2Helper.getResponse(LMSJava2Helper.java:58) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSHelper.sendRequest(LMSHelper.java:126) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.sendRequest(LMSApplet.java:1126) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.getAttemptState(LMSApplet.java:706) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.checkNotFinished(LMSApplet.java:666) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.LMSInitialize(LMSApplet.java:148) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
47:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Error calling LMSInitialize:
48:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - intSCORMError=101
49:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - SCORMErrorString=General exception
50:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - Diagnostic=java.lang.ClassFormatError: oracle/apps/ota/lms/LMSJava2Helper$1 at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSJava2Helper.getResponse(LMSJava2Helper.java:58) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSHelper.sendRequest(LMSHelper.java:126) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.sendRequest(LMSApplet.java:1126) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.getAttemptState(LMSApplet.java:706) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.checkNotFinished(LMSApplet.java:666) at oracle.apps.ota.lms.LMSApplet.LMSInitialize(LMSApplet.java:148) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
51:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - ERROR Initializing LMS
52:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In InitializeExecuted, blnSuccess=false, strErrorMessage=Error initializing communications with LMS
53:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - ERROR - LMS Initialize Failed
54:Tue Jun 14 02:16:28 UTC+0100 2016 - In DisplayError, strMessage=Error initializing communications with LMS
```

Comment: Please [edit] and include the information you get from pressing [OK] as instructed.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for responding and sorry for the delay. I just updated the question which includes the link for the debug information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LMSInitialize` has failed. You should pass the log file to whoever support/maintains the LMS system.